# lme4 Random Effect MLM

Tags: r, lme4, effects, mlm

I have a question about random effect in repeated measures design with 4 within-subjects factor (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`)

What the differences between these 2 ways of defining random effects:

- **Option 1.** `(1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | Subject)`
- **Option 2.** `(1 + x1 | Subject) + (1 + x2 | Subject) + (1 + x3 | Subject) + (1 + x4 | Subject)`

Answer (score 0):

The first option fits a model where the within-subject deviations of the effects of all the variables are correlated with each other. Assuming that each of the factors has two levels, this will lead to estimating 5 variances (one for the intercept, one each for the effects of the factors) and (5*4/2 = 10) covariances/correlations.

The second option is wrong/problematic because it ends up repeating the intercept-within-Subject component four times (these will be redundant/unidentifiable).  If you want the within-subject effects of the factors to be treated as independent, you can do

- `(1|Subject) + (0 + x1 | Subject) + (0 + x2 | Subject) + ...`  **or**
- use `glmmTMB` and `diag(1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | Subject)`  **or**
- use `afex::mixed()` and `(1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 || Subject)`